# Vim is too slow when parsing the long macro definition

Tags: vim

When I am using gvim to write systemverilog program, it goes very well....until I am using `define` syntax to define my macro. The macro contains several lines of code like this:

```
define my_macro(addr)\

assign a[addr] = b[addr];\

assign c[addr] = d[addr];\

....;\

assign name[addr] = your_name[addr];
```

And when the line number of the macro increases, gvim becomes extremely slow.

Why? May be syntax highlighting isn't efficient to handle this construct, but which kind of code in the syntax will cost this problem? I am using a `verilog_systemverilog.vim` syntax.

Comment: Your macro must be fairly bad to cause trouble — how many lines are represented by the three dots?  Are you sure there isn't a better way to write the code?  Which version of `gvim` are you using and on which platform?  For my money, there's likely a problem in the syntax extension.  I've had to work with some pretty long macros — unpleasantly long, but they weren't of my writing — and never spotted the problem, but I don't use the syntax module you're using.

Comment: about 20 lines, actually I never met this kind of problem before I use this syntax file. By the way, I am using Vim 8.0

Comment: Are you sure it's the syntax highlighting file which caused this problem?